# Events are not recovering in Akka 2.4.0 Persistence & Cassandra Journal Plugin 0.6

Tags: cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

I try to write an app using that is using Akka (version 2.4.0) Persistency and Cassandra Plugin (version 0.6, https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-cassandra) to recover from failures.
The events are being stored to cassandra with no issues, however, one I try to kill and actor, so the supervisor restarts it, the events are not received by `receiveRecover`.

It seems that the issue is with the plugin itself, as if I use shared LevelDB instead of cassandra, the events are being received on the recovery step.

Here is the implementation of my persistent actor:

```
    class SimplePersistentActor extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {

      def persistenceId: String = context.self.path.name

      override def preRestart(cause: Throwable, msg: Option[Any]) = {
        log.debug(s"Restarting ${getClass.getSimpleName}")
        super.preRestart(cause, msg)
      }

      override def postStop() = {
        log.debug(s"Stopping ${getClass.getSimpleName}")
        super.postStop()
      }

      var transactionData: Either[UninitializedData, RunningTransactionData] = Left(UninitializedData())

      def receiveCommand ={
        case msg @ TransactionStart(transactionId) =>
          persist(msg) { _ => }
          log.debug(s"Starting a transaction with id $transactionId")
          transactionData = Right(RunningTransactionData(transactionId, List()))

          /* Send a reply */
          sender() ! transactionId

        case msg @ TransactionData(data) =>
          persist(msg) { _ => }

          transactionData match {
            case Right(t: RunningTransactionData) =>
              val updatedTransaction = t.copy(data = t.data ::: List(data))
              log.debug(s"There are ${updatedTransaction.data.size} data items within a transaction ${t.transactionId}")
              transactionData = Right(updatedTransaction)

              /* Send a reply */
              sender() ! t.transactionId          

            case _ => log.error("Actor's transaction data is not initialized")
          }

        case TransactionEnd(transactionId) =>
          transactionData match {
            case Right(t: RunningTransactionData) =>
              log.debug(s"Ending a transaction with id ${t.transactionId}")
              transactionData = Left(UninitializedData())

              /* Send a reply */
              sender() ! t.transactionId

            case _ => log.error("Actor's transaction data is not initialized")
          }      

        case other =>
          log.debug(s"Unexpected event received: $other")
      }

      def receiveRecover = {
        case message =>
          log.debug(s"Recovery Step. Message $message received")
      }
    }
```

In both cases, that I describe above, the code doesn't change.
Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Tried to move to plugin of version 0.11, that is being developed here now https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra - still the same behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, that I receive an event `RecoveryCompleted`, so the only problem is that there are no persisted messages received, but the `RecoveryCompleted` is. Seems strange

Comment: I have the same problem with Akka 2.5.4 and akka-persistence-cassandra 0.55. Events are not replayed and state is restored to last snapshot.

Comment: There's a [bug in plugin](https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra/issues/237). You may run into it too.

Comment: This might be the bug we're all [seeing](https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra/issues/81)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same thing and found a fix that works for me. I know your question is pretty old but since I was seeing the same problem on the latest version of Akka Cassandra Persistence (0.86) I thought it would be worth mentioning.

The problem I had came from the following config.

```
cassandra-main-journal = ${cassandra-journal} {
  contact-points = ["localhost"]
  keyspace-autocreate = true
  tables-autocreate = true
  keyspace = "main_akka_journal"
}
```

So, take the default `cassandra-journal` config and override the `keyspace`. Then, like you're doing, overriding `persistenceId` in the Akka persistent actor to point to this config.

What happens if you do this is all writes to the Actor go the the `main_akka_journal` keyspace. On restarting the Actor you then get a `RecoveryCompleted` message but you don't see any of the messages you had written. However when you receive `RecoveryCompleted` the `lastSequenceNr` will be correct.

What's interesting is that if you have `keyspace-autocreate=true` you'll see two keyspaces where created. `main_akka_journal` and `akka`.

So the problem is the persistent actor is writing to the `main_akka_journal` keyspace, on restart it's reading events from the `akka` keyspace (which is empty) and then reading the `lastSequenceNr` from the `main_akka_journal` keyspace (which is correct).

The solution for me was this config:

```
cassandra-main-journal = ${cassandra-journal} {
  contact-points = ["localhost"]
  keyspace-autocreate = true
  tables-autocreate = true
  keyspace = "main_akka_journal"
  query-plugin = "cassandra-main-query-plugin"
}

cassandra-main-query-plugin = ${cassandra-query-journal} {
  write-plugin = "cassandra-main-journal"
}
```

Otherwise by default the `write-plugin` points to `cassandra-journal` and the `akka` keyspace.